# Setting legend text colour in Plotly 3.0

Tags: python, plotly, plotly.js

I have just installed the lastest Plotly (3.0) and I have not been able to set the legend text colour.

This is my code:

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import numpy as np

x = np.random.randn(1000)
y = np.random.randn(1000)

fig = go.FigureWidget({'x':x,'y':y,'type':'histogram2dcontour','colorscale':'Viridis'}],
layout=go.Layout(title='test',width=700,plot_bgcolor='rgba(0,0,0,0)',
paper_bgcolor='rgba(0,0,0,0)'))

fig.layout.titlefont.color = 'orange'
fig.layout.xaxis.color = 'white'
fig.layout.yaxis.color = 'white'
fig.layout.legend.font.size = 2000
fig.layout.legend.font.color = 'red'

fig
```

As can be seen below the legend text below remains the same. Weirdly the attributes of fig.layout.legend.font.color include capitalise, isdigit class methods etc.

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Any help much appreciated.

Thanks.

[image: Legend text unchanged.]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are using `histogram2contour` the color-bar on the right is not a legend but actually an object called `colorbar`. To update it you can configure it's properties in your trace. I have an example below where I make the tick marks orange and the title red. I used Jupyter Notebooks to create the example so I had to configure it to offline but you don't have too. [Here](https://plot.ly/python/reference/#histogram2dcontour-colorbar) is the documentation for the color-bar object.

```
 import plotly.graph_objs as go
 from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot
 init_notebook_mode(connected=True)

 import numpy as np

 x = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, size=500)
 y = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, size=500)

 trace = [go.Histogram2dContour(
         x = x,
         y = y,
     colorbar=dict(
         title='Colorbar',
         tickfont={'color':'#E90' },
         titlefont={"color":'#FF0000'}
     ),
 )]

 iplot(trace, filename = "Basic Histogram2dContour")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that's great. Didn't realise colorscale was a separate attribute to the legend. Thanks a lot!